# How to get only memory peak usage with /usr/bin/time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I am building a script with `usr/bin/time` program to monitor the RAM usage of a script and storing it in a variable so i can check if it is higher than a specified limit `$mlimit`, like this example using `ls /` as the command:

```bsh
$mlimit=512000 #512mb limit in kilobytes

$musage=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%M" ls / | rev | cut -f 1 | rev)
echo "RAM usage: $musage"
```

`/usr/bin/time` in this case returns first the output of the command and then the maximum resident set size (RAM usage). I thought then i could reverse the output, cut it to get the ram usage and reverse it back. But i get this output: `RAM usage: bin`. `bin` is the first directory returned by the `ls /` command. So my strategy to get the RAM usage is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `time` outputs the resource usage information on stderr, though can be told to write it elsewhere with `-o`

```
{
  musage=$(command time -o /dev/fd/4 -f %M ls / 4>&1 >&3 3>&-)
} 3>&1
```

Would record the max memory usage in the variable whilst leaving `ls`' stdout and stderr alone.

That works by duplicating the original fd 1 (stdout) to fd 3 outside the command substitution with `3>&1`, so that inside the command substitution, we can restore the original stdout for `ls` with `>&3` after having made the command substitution pipe available on fd 4.

Then `time` writes its output to that pipe via `/dev/fd/4`, while `ls` stdout is the original one.

Comment: Similarly, this would work too (if the STDOUT from the command in question matters) `foo=$(/usr/bin/time --format '%M' 2>&1 ls / 1>/dev/null)`

Comment: @cnamejj, not really, `$foo` would also contain `ls` errors if any any you're losing the output of `ls`.

Comment: True, but this would work in that case `foo=$(/usr/bin/time --format '%M' 2>&1 'ls bad-filename-here 2>/dev/null >/dev/null' | tail -1)` where the `tail -1` make sure you don't get the error message from `time` about the RC of the `ls.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas could you please provide more information of what is going on with this solution? It seems too advanced for me so i would like to understand it a little better. Thank you very much.

Comment: @heresthebuzz, see if the edit clarifies it.

Comment: Yes, that is clearer now! How can i research for more info about this `n>&m` approach? Is there a name to look for? Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas i was trying to run your solution in another machine and i got this error: `time: /dev/fd/4: No such file or directory`. Is there any workaround for your solution to work?

Comment: @heresthebuzz, systems without `/dev/fd/n` support are getting rare these days. Which system is it?

Comment: @heresthebuzz, your question is tagged with "linux" which has `/dev/fd/n` support (symlinks to `/proc/self/fd/n` there). Are you trying to run that on a non-Linux system? Would that system have bash? I'd also expect `time` on non-Linux systems not to support that `-f %M`.

Comment: I am running it inside a docker image with ubuntu. I previously tested your code with WSL only and it worked very good, but inside the docker image it throws this error i mentioned.

Comment: If your docker container has /proc mounted, you can replace `/dev/fd` with `/proc/self/fd` above.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas i managed to get it working changing `/dev/fd/4` to `/dev/fd/2`, but memory value is not being stored in the variable. Do i have to change `4` to `2` anywhere in the command to store the value in the variable?